# Google Apps - Unable to Access Shared Mailboxes

Tags: g-suite

We have several dozen users that access shared mailboxes but have lost the link next to there email address. I have a Google support case open but it is still an outstanding issue.

The workaround they gave me was a direct link to the account.

https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com/b/shared-mailbox@domain.com/u/user@domain.com/

This doesn't work for me and I usually have to wait several hours to hear back from Google Support.

Does anyone else have a working workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no other work arounds for this issue. Google has listed this issue as resolved on 9/10/2010.

Comment: Same thing happened to me yesterday when I switched to the new allow Google apps accounts to sign in to Google Accounts.  It totally screwed everything up.  My users can't figure how to log in to the services they normally use.